# Image not rendering in rails application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Here i have added images to directory of rails application which is under

```
\app\assets\images\products\mobile
```

directory

i have added the img src in the html.erb file, but the image is not rendering on the browser...how can i make image render in the browser.

here is how  i have added image.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <img src="images/products/mobile-1.jpg">
    <div class="product-description">
    <h3>IPhone 5s</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `<img src="/assets/images/products/mobile-1.jpg">`

Comment: @Pavan i tried that but still not rendering image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `image_tag`, that will automatically pick images from assets. Your image should be stored in `assets/images/products/`  path.
For example

```
image_tag("products/mobile-1.jpg")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/images/products/mobile-1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
<%= image_tag "products/mobile-1.jpg" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use image_tag for that.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <%= image_tag("images/products/mobile-1.jpg") %>
    <div class="product-description">
    <h3>IPhone 5s</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```